# ActiveRecord Rail 3 query to include results that do not have an existing relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there a way to query for items using a :joins or :includes but also to return, in the same query, results that do not have a corresponding relation?

the current example query

```
Company.find(1).users.includes(:billing_statuses).where('billing_statuses.expires < ?', Time.now)
```

That should return all users that have expired billing_statuses, however, the ultimate goal is to get all 'un-billed' users, and that would include users that do not yet have :billing_statuses relation.

is there a way to combine this in one query?

An alternative I have explored is getting all the users for a company and then subtracting the users which do NOT have an expired bill. But I feel that is not the most optimal solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`User.where(company_id: 1).joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN billing_statuses ON billing_statuses.user_id = users.id").where("billing_statuses.expires < ? or billing_statuses.id IS NULL", Time.now)`